# Identify a broken component

Tags: identification

I'm taking apart a misbehaving USB hard drive, and I've spotted a broken component on the PCB for the hard drive itself. Fortunately, there appears to be an intact, identical component on another part of the board, but I can't identify it.

The code on the top is`FBD` (sorry for the awful phone picture), it appears to have two connections, has been deliberately surrounded by a ground trace, and is 4.9 x 2.3 mm

[image]

[image]

Comment: That might be an SMD fuse.

Comment: What did you do to the poor little thing to blow the lid off?

Comment: @vladimir-cravero Measuring the impedance across the intact one gives a value in the megaohms. My first thought might be a voltage-limiting diode, but I can't identify it.

Comment: @VladimirCravero I doubt a fuse with a guard trace around it. Then both leads connect to somewhat symmetric looking RC filters and symmetric tracks to the SOT23.

Comment: Don't see why an SMD fuse would need a guard ring...  oscillator resonator MAYBE but more likely some kind of sensor ... vibration perhaps? the odd mounting angle must be significant. Do both sensors point towards the platter centre?

Comment: Aaaaand it seems to have a polarity, something that fuses do not have. Can op perhaps do a little of reverse engineering on that portion of circuit?

Comment: I doubt the guard trace is grounded, why go through the effort of an extra via if the ground plane is adjacent to the trace.

Comment: @jippie - the SOT23 has a code AAARPQ. Nothing back on google.

Comment: I bet the guard trace connects to a buffered output ... probably one of the SOT23 pins.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Not to one of the SOT23 pins

Comment: I happen to have a drive here that has this exact part of the PCB, but unpopulated. The guard trace in the lower image is not connected to the SOT-23, it is connected to one of the two RC combinations at the end of the parallel trace. BTW both parallel signal traces are connected to the corners of the SOT23-5, pins 3 and 4 if I [count correctly](https://images.duckduckgo.com/iur/?f=1&image_host=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wvshare.com%2Fimg%2Fpinout%2FTPS61040_l.jpg&u=http://www.waveshare.com/img/pinout/TPS61040_l.jpg).

Comment: What is the text on the good part? The photos are too blurry to see.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast It's in the body of the post -- FBD

Comment: Be aware that any of the parts it could be (see also Olin's answer), due to prior elimination steps above, are very unlikely to die at all, let alone in such a violent way. So you must be absolutely aware of the high likelihood that something else broke first, over-stressing this part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a piezoelectric ceramic shock sensor / acceleration sensor, likely made by muRata. I've seen up to 3 of them strategically located on hard drive boards. They are labeled as "SK" on WD PCBs, but aren't labeled on Maxtor HDs. Here are links for info and 2 datasheets:

https://www.murata.com/en-us/products/productdetail?partno=PKGS-00GXP1-R

https://www.murata.com/en-us/products/productdata/8797617225758/00GXP1-E.pdf?1452655830000

http://www1.futureelectronics.com/doc/MURATA/PKGS-00LD-R.pdf

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing it is either a Hall effect sensor or a ceramic filter.

The guard trace around it means this component is sensitive to capacitive coupling from other traces. The odd angle implies it is sensitive to orientation, probably due to magnetic fields since the guard trace should be shielding it well enough from electric fields.